# Safari not displaying some of my content

Tags: python, html, css, django, safari

so i have an issue where everything works as it should in chrome but in safari some things are just not displayed  as if they weren't there.

in my nav it should have products, about, contact and blog in chrome it displays as such, but in safari the contact link is missing. when i checked the inspector its not even hidden its just not in the code.

and one of my filters on the product page again works fine in chrome but in safari the indiviudals tab just doesn't display any content and the medical schools tab is missing one of its items.

[image: safari][image: chrome][image: safari][image: chrome]

product page

```
<section class="resource-list-block content-block">
<div class="product-overview col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-xl-offset-1 col-xl-10 resource-list-block__list">

        {% for product_page in product_pages %}

        {% if product_page.get_content_model.public %}
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-xl-4 cover resource-list-block__list__item resource-list-block__list__item--important filterable product-list-block__list__item filtered-cat filtered-filt" data-category="{{ product_page.get_content_model.specialties.all|specialties }}" data-filter="{{ product_page.get_content_model.tags.all|tags }}">
                    <a href="{{product_page.get_absolute_url}}">
                        {% include "includes/product-cover.html" with product=product_page.get_content_model.product %}
                    </a>
                </div>

        {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}  
</div>
```

product-item section

```
{% load staticfiles compress %}<div class="sans-serif cover-page">
<figure class="figure-cover" style="background-color:#{{product.theme_color}} !important;">
    <div class="cover-img center-block"><img src="{{product.element_icon.url}}" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="{{product.title}} Image"></div>
    <div class="product-count">
    <div class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><span class="small-text"> {{ product.updates_per_year }} updates per year</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="text-center type-name">
        <h3 class="sans-serif">{{ product_page.get_content_model.product_type | upper }}</h3>
        <h4 class="sans-serif hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs">{{ product_page.get_content_model.editor_text }} <br> {{ product_page.get_content_model.editor_title_text }}</h4>
        <h4 class="sans-serif">ISSN {{ product.issn }}</h4>
    </div>
</figure>
<figure class="product-content" {% if product.theme_color = 'AF1F24' %} style="background-color:#f2e4e5 !important" {% endif%}>
   <div class="cover-img center-block"><img src="{{product.element_icon_alt.url}}" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="{{product.title}} Image"></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <h2 class="text-center type-name">{{ product.title | upper }}</h2>
    <figcaption>
        <p>{{ product_page.get_content_model.intro }}</p>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

and the nav code

```
{% load pages_tags i18n future  %}{% spaceless %}<ul class="decker-menu generic-nav-list generic-nav-list--horizontal theme" id="hero-nav">
{% for child_page in page_branch %}
   {% if child_page.in_menu %}
    <li class="decker-menu__item">
        <a {% if child_page == page or child_page in page.get_ascendants %} class="active important" {% endif %} href="{% if child_page.slug|slice:":4" == 'http' %}{{ child_page.slug }}{% else %} {{ child_page.get_absolute_url }}{% endif %}" >{{ child_page.title }}</a>
    </li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}<li class="decker-menu__item login-btn"><a href="/decker" >Login</a></li><li class="decker-menu__item decker-menu__item--menu-button icon-hamburger open-menu"><a href="#">Menu</a></li></ul>{% endspaceless %}
```

Comment: Where is `page_branch` defined?

Comment: its just a field in the db @Sayse

Answer (score 0):

had to go into mezzanine on safari then remove the content save and refresh the page then go back and re-add it to fix the issue. then repeated that step to fix the issue in firefox.... so weird

thanks!